# Me carga por 2 veces la tabla al pasar parámetros por una función de Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, base-de-datos, datatables

Tengo una tabla que por defecto se rellena con datos de la BBDD, según unos parámetros que recibe por GET. Ahora intento que esos datos, se filtren por fechas. Tengo 2 selectores de fechas (inicio y fin). Cuando se selecciona la fecha fin, salta una función JS que me recoge las fechas seleccionadas y esas fechas las utilizo para "confeccionar" la query de llamada a la BBDD. El problema, es que cuando pasa esto, no me borra la tabla anterior y me "pinta" la nueva tabla encima de la anterior.

Este seria el PHP donde se dibuja la tabla, según la query que se extrae de la BBDD.

```
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while($row4=mysqli_fetch_array($query4)) {
         ?>
          <tr class="gradeX">
            <?php if($row9['idpermisos']==1){ ?>    
            <td>
                  <!-- Las opciones de ver/modificar y eliminar solo estan disponibles para los administradores. -->
                  <button class="btn btn-default"><a href="zborrar.php?tabla=estadisticas&idtabla=<?php echo $row4['id_estad']; ?>" onclick="return confirmar()"><i class="fa fa-trash">  Eliminar</i></a></button>
                </td>
                <?php } ?>
              <?php if($row9['idpermisos']!=1){ ?> 
              <td></td>
              <?php } ?> 
                <td>
                <?php
                    echo cambiafh_a_normal($row4['fecha_estad']);
                ?>
                </td>       
            <td>
                <?php
                $query2=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id='$row4[usuario_estad]'");
                $row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
                echo $row2['nombre'];
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php
                $query3=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM contactos WHERE id='$row4[contacto_estad]'");
                $row3=mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
                ?><a href="base.php?id=modificar<?php echo $table; ?>&idtabla=<?php echo $row3['id']; ?>&tab=1"><?php echo $row3['nombre']; ?></a>
            </td>
            <td>
          <?php 
            $accion = $row4['accion_estad'];
            $final = str_replace(" ALTA","<span style='color:red; font-weight:900;'> ALTA</span>",$accion);
            echo $final;
           ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
```

Este seria el código donde capturo las fechas de inicio y fin y lanzo la llamada a la función JS

```
 <div class="page-title">
  <div class="form-actions text-left col-xs-4">
    <h5><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <?php echo ucwords($tabla); ?></h5>
  </div>

  <!-- Mostramos el botón de borrar estadisticas, solo si el usuario es un admin.  -->
  <?php if($row9['idpermisos']==1){ ?>      
  <div class="form-actions text-left col-xs-8">
    <label><input type="date" id="fecha_ini" name="fecha_ini" value=""></>Inicio</label> 
    <label><input type="date" id="fecha_fin" name="fecha_fin" value="" onchange="actualizar()"></>Final</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-desvincular" onclick="borraestadisticas(<?php echo $id_user ?>)">Borrar Estadisticas</button> 
  </div>
  <?php } ?> 

</div>
```

Esta seria la función JS que recoge los datos

```
  function actualizar(){

    var param = {
      fecha_ini: document.getElementById("fecha_ini").value,
      fecha_fin: document.getElementById("fecha_fin").value,
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: param,
        url: "estadisticas.php",
        method: "post",
        beforeSend: function () {
          $("#respuesta").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#respuesta").html(data);
        }
    });
  }
```

y por ultimo las querys

```
<?php 

if (((isset($_POST['fecha_ini'])) AND ($_POST['fecha_ini']!= NULL)) AND ((isset($_POST['fecha_fin'])) AND ($_POST['fecha_fin']!= NULL))){

  $fecha_iborrar = $_POST['fecha_ini'];
  $fecha_fborrar = $_POST['fecha_fin'];

  if ((isset($_GET['usuario'])) AND (($_GET['usuario'])=="admin")) {

    $query4=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM estadisticas WHERE fecha_estad BETWEEN '$fecha_iborrar' AND '$fecha_fborrar'");

  }elseif ((isset($_GET['idtabla'])) AND (($_GET['idtabla'])!= $row9[id])){  

    $id_user = $_GET['idtabla'];
    $query4=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM estadisticas WHERE usuario_estad='$id_user' AND fecha_estad BETWEEN '$fecha_iborrar' AND '$fecha_fborrar'");

  }else{ 

    $query4=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM estadisticas WHERE usuario_estad='$row9[id]' AND fecha_estad BETWEEN '$fecha_iborrar' AND '$fecha_fborrar'");

  }


}else{ 

  if ((isset($_GET['usuario'])) AND (($_GET['usuario'])=="admin")) {

    $query4=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM estadisticas ORDER BY fecha_estad DESC");

  }elseif ((isset($_GET['idtabla'])) AND (($_GET['idtabla'])!= $row9[id])){ 

    $id_user = $_GET['idtabla'];
    $query4=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM estadisticas WHERE usuario_estad='$id_user' ORDER BY fecha_estad DESC");

  }else{  

    $query4=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM estadisticas WHERE usuario_estad='$row9[id]' ORDER BY fecha_estad DESC");

  }
}

?>
```

La primera vez que carga la pagina, entra en el else de las querys, pues no existen ($_POST['fecha_ini']) ni ($_POST['fecha_fin'])), pero al lanzar la función actualizar, me mantiene la primera tabla que se dibujo (al pasar por el else) y luego me dibuja encima la nueva tabla, teniendo en cuenta las fechas de inicio y fin.

Que estoy haciendo mal ?.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

no veo la función que escribe el html de la tabla, sólo el html. Prueba a hacer una tercera consulta, a ver si te suma los datos de esta última consulta a los de las dos tablas que ya tienes dibujadas o bien te repite el patrón de primera tabla + última consulta. Si te suma los datos, el problema tal vez sea que no inicializas en blanco la variable o el div donde se guarda el html de la tabla antes de hacer la consulta.

Comment: Hola DigiSoul. Gracias por la respuesta. Al final conseguí solucionarlo sin JS.